# Bose Home-theater selection

Tags: home-studio, theater

I am trying to decide which of Bose home theater system is good for our living room. We have low sealing big living room (not huge) and 50 inch TV.

Please let me know. just fyi we got two infant boys (just in case) they pick and pull lot of wires all the time. :)